# Catalog Price rule special price date field

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

Trying to create a catalog rule where all products not on an existing sale would be discounted by X%. Here is what i have so far: http://prntscr.com/h8d2ae

Everything works fine, except for the line that looks at the expiration date of existing special price. It should only apply the discount for products with expired special prices, but the system is not recognizing the "Greater than/less than" operator for dates.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is there another work around?

Comment: Does it work OK if the date operator is just 'equals'?

Comment: No it’s not validating against any date operators.